# Convert a Word document with different but grouped line responses to an Excel/CSV document?

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word

I'm tried to convert ~4,000 user entries (ex. from a user database in MS word) to a workable excel/csv document. Each entry, if fully completed, would be in the following format:

```
State
Full Name
Email
Organization
Position
```

The entries I have are variations of the above format (meaning that not all the fields were entered). The 1st line is almost always the state, every entry has a full name, not all entries have emails, organization listed, or the position.

For instance the first page of data might look like the following (Each entry is separated by a blank line):

---

```
California
John Doe
johndoe@gmail.com

Jane Smith
janesmith@yahoo.com
Apple Inc.

Alabama
Mark Stein
markstein@hotmail.com
Yahoo Corporation
Data Manager
```

---

How do I convert the following above entries (in Microsoft Word) to an Excel/CSV file that would look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Updated & removed (@JosephC changed the incoming data format)

Comment: Your data above shows each entry on **one** *row* with an assumed blank row between each entry. However, when I look at the edit option for the post, your data shows as stacked, like `Row 1: State`, `Row 2: Full Name`, `Row 3: Email`, etc. Which way is your data *actually* setup? It may change how this question is approached.

Comment: What do you mean by "a user database in Word".  Usually these are created as part of a mail merge, and saved as an Access document linked to the Word document.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: to TotsieMae: each 'user entry' is consisted of several adjacent rows with a blank row between each entry. The entries are separated by blank rows.

Comment: to Ron Rosenfeld: I am starting off with a microsoft word document consisting of these user entries that were likely downloaded from some user database which I don't have access to.

Comment: Are the fields (where present) always in the same order?

Comment: The fields if present are in the same order, but they are inconsistent in the sense that only the full name is present. the other fields (state, email, organization, and title) are not always present and varies by individual.

Comment: How would you differentiate between a company/organization and a position?

Comment: If you want to respond in comments to other commenters, use the following syntax: `@JosephC`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following algorithm for identifying the kind of information of each detail:

- If the line exists in a list of states, then it is a state name.
- If the line contains an `@` character, then it's an email.
- The remaining fields are filled in the following order of precedence: `FullName`, `Organization`, `Position`.

For VBA, a `Dictionary` is a suitable data structure for the list of states.

The following code builds up a disconnected recordset with the parsed data. Add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** and **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** (latest version, usually 6.1), from **Tools** -> **References...**.

```
' Generate list of states
Dim states As New Scripting.Dictionary
states.Add "California", 1
states.Add "Alabama", 1

' Fill the recordset
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Fields.Append "State", adVarChar, 30
rs.Fields.Append "FullName", adVarChar, 100
rs.Fields.Append "Email", adVarChar, 100
rs.Fields.Append "Organization", adVarChar, 100
rs.Fields.Append "Position", adVarChar, 100

rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.Open

Dim p As Paragraph
Dim nameEntered As Boolean
Dim organizationEntered As Boolean

rs.AddNew
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Dim text As String
    text = p.Range.text
    text = Left(text, Len(text) - 1) 'remove the newline from the end of the string

    If Len(text) = 0 Then
        rs.Update
        rs.AddNew
        nameEntered = False
        organizationEntered = False
    ElseIf states.Exists(text) Then
        rs!State = text
    ElseIf text Like "*@*" Then
        rs!Email = text
    ElseIf Not nameEntered Then
        rs!FullName = text
        nameEntered = True
    ElseIf Not organizationEntered Then
        rs!Organization = text
        organizationEntered = True
    Else
        rs!Position = text
    End If
Next

rs.MoveFirst
```

Once you have a recordset with this information, there are a number of possible options:

- You could use the recordset's `GetString` method to return a CSV-compatible string, and then save that CSV as a file using VBA's built-in file functions, or using the `FileSystemObject`.
- You could create an instance of Excel, create a new workbook, and use the Excel `Range`'s `CopyFromRecordset` method to paste the data into a worksheet. You could then save the worksheet as a CSV.
- You could try to find a third-party package that generates a CSV froma recordset, or any 2D array (via the recordset's `GetRows` method).

Since in your question, you say you are looking for either an Excel or CSV document, I would go with the second option. Add a reference to the **Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library** (your precise version may vary), and then you can do the following:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.UserControl = True

Dim book As Excel.Workbook
Set book = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
book.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
book.SaveAs "C:\path\to\output\file.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a beginner when it comes to VBA so i followed these instructions (with several small changes) and was able to resolve my issue: http://www.gmayor.com/convert_labels_into_mail_merge.htm